# Select rows from many User

Tags: sql, select

I have many people in a table e.g.

```
Name    Grade (INT)
Jim     50%
John    86%
Jane    65%
Joanne  75%
Stewart 95%
Kate    23%
Betty   98%
Bill    73%
Bobby   54%
```

I want to SELECT the top 3 people from the table.

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: it depends on particular dbms product. see here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Answer (score 2):

If you want any three users then it will help you

`SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY Grade desc LIMIT 3`

Comment: @P_Hamerla pls see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `in` operator and a subquery:

```
select * from {table} where {column} in (select top 3 {column} from User)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
select * from table where column in ('abc','def', ...) limit 3
```

Comment: OP mentioned `top 3`, which leads me to believe (s)he is using sql server, which doesn't know `limit 3`

Answer (score -2):

try

select * from table where field LIKE('asd', 'def', ...)

Comment: That's not how `like` works